# How to track time of user intracting with my Ads

Tags: android, ads, time-tracking

How can i track timing of user watching my ads, 
I want to give user point if user watch my ad for 5 seconds,
I don't use any code  yet. How can i track the time user spend on my Ad
Any Hint Of Help will be useful for me.

Comment: Which ad platform are you using?

Comment: Hay there i m using Ad Mob Interstitial ad

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett  Ad Mob Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I track the time,   When user Click The Ad And when he closed the ad,